# I need to group the value based on some attribute and populate it

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to group the value based on some attribute and populate it.

The input XML is below, and the duplicate jobid is defined as the (|) separator.

While generating actual o/p I need to group by jobid and generate sequences number for duplicate jobids. How would I do this?

```
  <employes>
    <job>
        <jobid>125</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>1011</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|1</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|2</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>1010</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|1</jobid>
    </job>
</employes>
```

Expected result: I need to group the values based on Division and populate i.e.

```
<employes>
    <job>
        <jobnum>1</jobnum>
        <jobid>123</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobnum>2</jobnum>
        <jobid>123</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobnum>3</jobnum>
        <jobid>123</jobid>
    </job>  
    <job>
        <jobid>125</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>1010</jobid>
    </job>  
    <job>
        <jobid>1011</jobid>
    </job>
</employes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0 (question was originally tagged XSLT 2.0 only) you should be able to use `xsl:for-each-group` and group by the number before `|` in `jobid`...

**XML Input**

```
<employes>
    <job>
        <jobid>125</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>1011</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|1</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|2</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>1010</jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>123|1</jobid>
    </job>
</employes>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="job" group-by="substring-before(concat(jobid,'|'),'|')">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(concat(jobid,'|'),'|')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="job[contains(jobid,'|')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::jobid)]"/>
            <jobnbr><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></jobnbr>
            <jobid><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(jobid,'|')"/></jobid>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<employes>
   <job>
      <jobnbr>1</jobnbr>
      <jobid>123</jobid>
   </job>
   <job>
      <jobnbr>2</jobnbr>
      <jobid>123</jobid>
   </job>
   <job>
      <jobnbr>3</jobnbr>
      <jobid>123</jobid>
   </job>
   <job>
      <jobid>125</jobid>
   </job>
   <job>
      <jobid>1010</jobid>
   </job>
   <job>
      <jobid>1011</jobid>
   </job>
</employes>
```

Comment: I  want  XSLT 1.0 also.